# How to toggle background color of rows in *ngFor in Angular / TypeScript?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, background-color

I'm a beginner using Angular 6. I want to change the background color of a row of the table when I click on it, and when I reclick on it, set it back to the original color.

I've tried to understand different solutions here on SO, but eventually couldn't make it work. 
Heres what happen: I click on a row, it highlights it. If then i click on line 2, it unhighlights the first one. But if i click on line 3 it will highlight both 2 and 3. If I click on 4, only 2 and 4 will be highlighted and 3 will be unhighlighted... so **only lines on uneven numbers can be highlighted with the code atm.**

Here's my TypeScript :
`public changeTableRowColor(idx: any) {this.rowClicked = idx;}`

Here's my HTML :

```
<tr *ngFor="let ApiDataFile of filteredApiDataFiles; let idx=index; let even=even"
    [style.background-color]="rowClicked == idx ? 'yellow' : (even ? '#ffffff' : 'f1f1f1')"
    (click)="changeTableRowColor(idx)">
  <td>{{ ApiDataFile.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ ApiDataFile.surname }}</td>
</tr>
```

---

Solution :

```
  <tr *ngFor="let ApiDataFile of filteredApiDataFiles; let idx=index; let even=even"
  [style.background-color]="ApiDataFile.rowClicked ? 'yellow' : (even ? '#ffffff' : '#f1f1f1')"
  (click)="ApiDataFile.rowClicked = !ApiDataFile.rowClicked">
  <td>{{ ApiDataFile.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ ApiDataFile.surname }}</td>
</tr>
```

what I expect : i can highlight multiple rows, and unhighlight them by clicking on it.

EDIT : posted the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put dummy property in your object and handle it on click.

```
<tr *ngFor="let ApiDataFile of filteredApiDataFiles; let idx=index; let even=even"
    [style.background-color]="ApiDataFile.rowClicked ? 'yellow' : (even ? 'red' : 'green')"
    (click)="ApiDataFile.rowClicked = !ApiDataFile.rowClicked">
      <td>{{ ApiDataFile.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ ApiDataFile.surname }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a condition in `changeTableRowColor`:

```
changeTableRowColor(idx: any) { 
  if(this.rowClicked === idx) this.rowClicked = -1;
  else this.rowClicked = idx;
}
```

This will set `rowClicked` to -1 if currently clicked rowId is equal to the previously clicked row id.

> Here's a Working [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-color-of-clicked-row-in-angular-table?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: hello thanks for ur time. After adding this line, the row isn't highlighted anymore when I click on it.

With my previous code heres what happen:

I click on a row, it highlights it. If then i click on line 2, it unhighlights the first one. But if i click on line 3 it will highlight both 2 and 3. If I click on 4, only 2 and 4 will be highlighted and 3 will be unhighlighted... so only lines on uneven numbers can be highlighted.

Comment: Strange. Can you please check the Working Sample StackBlitz? It's working fine for me in there.

Comment: I couldn't seem to make it work, but your solution was very similar to Parshwa's, so it was probably a misunderstanding on my side.

Thanks for ur help mate

Answer (score 0):

you could add [ngClass]={'classToApply':clicked===index} coupled with (click)="step=index; '"

Something like:

```
<li [ngClass]="{classToApply: clicked===index}"(click)="step=index;">Data</li>
```